# How to export and download excel file through codeigniter, excel file is not creating(download)

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
//query fetching data from database
if (!$query)
            return false; //if there is no data in query return false
            // Starting the PHPExcel library
            $this->load->library('PHPExcel');//loading library
            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");

            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

            // Field names in the first row
            $fields = $query->list_fields();
            $col = 0;
    //add data into cells
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
                $col++;
            }

            // Fetching the table data
            $row = 2;
            foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
                $col = 0;
                foreach ($fields as $field) {
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data->$field);
                    $col++;
                }
                $row++;
            }

            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'csv');
    //creating excel sheet
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="subscribers_sheet.csv"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
            header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
            header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
            header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
            header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

            $objWriter->save('php://output');// inserting data into excel sheet
```

Comment: Any error in log?

Answer (score 0):

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);

header("Pragma: no-cache");

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="subscribers_sheet.csv"');

$objWriter->save("php://output");

Comment: Please add some context to your answer and explain how it solves the OP's problem. As it stands now, a few lines of code with no explanation, it is not particularly helpful.